# Is it normal to wear out the rear tire with in a few months when using a trainer?

Tags: tire, training, innertube, wear

Early this year I attached my bicycle to a trainer, around the December time frame of 2011. The rear tire and inner tuber where shot by March of 2012. Riding about 24 Miles per week. Is this normal with the use of a trainer?

I have had the bicycle since 2004, and the tires were in good condition prior to attaching to the trainer. I have never had a flat, and the tread wear was good, probably had about 3000 Miles on the rear tire. After 3-4 months on the trainer the rear tire was bald, and the nylon belting was stringing on the inside of the tire, and the inner tube could not hold pressure long even with patching.

I ended up just order a new tire and inner tube for the front wheel and rotated the old tire and tube set to the rear wheel. Should I plan to do this every time I hook up the trainer for the season?

Comment: Not with a LeMond Revolution Trainer :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is common and is a result of the constant friction and increased heat of the small roller on the trainer. Larger diameter rollers will see lower degradation of the tire, but it will still be a problem.

Most riders I know use less expensive tires, or older tires that they no longer trust for use on the road when they switch to the trainer.

Answer (score 7):

Trainers are notorious for chewing up regular tires.

They do sell trainer tires that are built to take the rubbing and wear that a trainer dishes out. What a lot of people do is buy a cheap wheel (Such as a neuvation or similar), throw a trainer tire on it and use that when they mount their bike to the trainer.

Answer (score 6):

As @GaryRay has stated trainers are tough on tires. One condition that accelerates the wear is low pressure in the tire and high pressure on the roller. Many riders would not think of going for a ride without checking tire pressure but forget about checking the trainer tire. The low pressure on the tire and high roller pressure generates heat from the deflection of the sidewall as the wheel spins. the heat damages the tire. Also verify that the tire /wheel is as perpendicular to the roller as possible.

Comment: +1 Good points - when I switch to the trainer, I put a floor pump next to my bike and top of the pressure about every other ride.